# WordPress изменение пунктов стандартного меню в админке

Tags: wordpress

Необходимо переименовать "Записи" в админке на любое свое название. Использую код:

```
function edit_admin_menus() {
    global $menu;
    global $submenu;
    $menu[5][0] = 'Книги';
    $submenu['edit.php'][5][0] = 'Все книги';
    $submenu['edit.php'][10][0] = 'Добавить книгу';
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'edit_admin_menus' );
function change_post_object_label() {
    global $wp_post_types;
    $labels = &$wp_post_types['post']->labels;
    $labels->name = 'Книги';
    $labels->singular_name = 'Книги';
    $labels->add_new = 'Добавить книгу';
    $labels->add_new_item = 'Добавить книгу';
    $labels->edit_item = 'Изменить книгу';
    $labels->new_item = 'Книга';
    $labels->view_item = 'Посмотреть книгу';
    $labels->search_items = 'Искать книгу';
    $labels->not_found = 'Ничего не найдено';
    $labels->not_found_in_trash = 'Корзина пуста';
}
```

[image: Верхняя панель]

Однако, в верхней панели во вкладке "Добавить" остается старый пункт. Есть решение?

Comment: ИМХО. Проще было "переименовать" в лангпаке.  https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/ в помощь. Или https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/say-what/

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, но вопрос все еще актуален - я не очень люблю плагины. (Обычно, использую не более 5).

Comment: Плагинофобия лечится изучением матчасти. Как раз это делать нужно не в теме, а плагином (своим или нет - другой вопрос). Все эти строки задаются в переводах (лангпаках). Подменить лангпак можно и без плагина (лень гуглить функцию, но она же и в плагинах). А вот сделать его.. Ну можно десткопным поэтидом или др. дестопным ПО. У комсомольцев в гамаках свои причуды..

Answer (score 2):

Для изменения пункта в верхнем меню укажите строку `name_admin_bar`:

```
$labels->name_admin_bar = 'Книгу';
```

Answer (score 0):

Этот способ меняет пункт только в админке. На сайте снова будут записи.

```
$labels->name_admin_bar = 'Книгу';
```

В общем решил этот вопрос костылем:

```
$('#wp-admin-bar-new-post').find('a').html('Книгу');
```

Comment: По приведённому фрагменту непонятно, в какой момент вызывается функция `change_post_object_label()`.

Если привязать её к действию, которое выполняется и на внешней части сайта — например, `init` — пункт будет меняться и там.